# Why does it not orderby = date?

Tags: database, date, content-management-system, typo3, typoscript

In the *backend* I filled out the **date** field for several content elements in this format `24-12-2011`.

In the *database* of typo3 the date value looks like this: `1293836400`

I want to render some content using the date as a condition..

```
10 < styles.content.getLeft
10 {
  select {
    orderby = date
    pidInList.field = uid
  }
}
```

Okay okay.. this worked fine. I see the contentelements all is cool.
But then I was curious if it still works when I change the position of the pages which contain those contentelements.

*BEFORE Pagetree:*

page200 with content element with date 1-1-2011
page201 with content element with date 1-2-2011
page202 with content element with date 1-3-2011
page203 with content element with date 1-4-2011

*Frontend Output:*
content element with date 1-1-2011, content element with date 1-2-2011, content element with date 1-3-2011, content element with date 1-4-2011

*AFTER (changend positon of pages in the backend) Pagetree:*

**page202 with content element with date 1-3-2011**
page201 with content element with date 1-2-2011
**page200 with content element with date 1-1-2011**
page203 with content element with date 1-4-2011

*Frontend Output:*
content element with date **1-3-2011**, content element with date 1-2-2011, content element with date **1-1-2011**, content element with date 1-4-2011 (IT CHANGED!)

So it changend the position in my frontend output. BUT that is irrelevant because I declared: "orderby = date(!)" and not "orderby = sorting". So why does is sort it by order? I dont get it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields in `orderBy` are not escaped. As `date` is a function in MySQL, you have to escape it yourself:

```
10 < styles.content.getLeft
10 {
  select {
    orderby = `date`
    pidInList.field = uid
  }
}
```